# Why are Spanish adverbs formed using the feminine?

Tags: etimología, género, adverbios

To form adverbs in Spanish, you take your chosen adjective, e.g. **lent@** - *slow*, turn it into the feminine form, **lenta**, then add *-mente*, ***lentamente*** - *slowly*.

Why do you use the feminine form here?

In most gender-neutral cases, Spanish takes the masculine form, but this doesn't, why not?

Comment: Note that unmarked adverbs use the masculine (technically neuter) form of adjectives. Using -mente isn't always required

Comment: Like *mucho* do you mean?

Comment: That's actually probably a pretty clear example of one (as it doesn't even admit the -mente formation).  But you can do it with a number of other adjectives that can be marked: *Ella trasnochó trabajando muy duro (=**duramente**)*.  These days it's rare but for a handful (most of which are given explicit entries in the DRAE and are rarely marked, like *rápido*)

Comment: It is the same in French.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<sup>(English version; loose Spanish translation follows)</sup>

## Latin *mens, mentis* produced ablative *mente*

This practice began all the way back in Classical Latin, passed into Vulgar Latin and Proto-Romance and thence to all modern Western Romance tongues: Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, Catalan, Occitan, French, and the many related neighboring languages in that group.

The Spanish **feminine** substantive *la mente* derives from the same ultimate Latin origin as does its *-mente* suffix used to derive adverbs from adjectives: *mens/mentis*, a **feminine** noun from the third declension. This noun meant *thought* or ***mind***, the latter being its English cognate through a common Proto-Indo-European ancestor.

The [Wiktionary entry for Latin *mens*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mens#Latin) observes:

> In most classical Latin, the ablative singular *mente* was used with a feminine adjective to form a phrasal adverb that expressed a person's state of mind, such as *vēlōcī mente* ‎(“quick-mindedly, with a quick mind”)

> - 29-19 BCE, Virgil, Aenid, book 4, line 105:
>   *sensit enim **simulata mente** locutam‎*
>   for she realized that (she) had spoken with false purpose.

> In Late Latin, this construction began to be extended to other adjectives and uses as well, and in Vulgar Latin and the later Romance languages, it became a general adverbial suffix.

[Latin’s ablative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_(Latin)) had quite a few uses that we now represent with a separate preposition instead of nominal case inflection. One of these prepositions used to translate the ablative case is *with*, so using *mens* in the ablative *mente* meant “with (a/the) mind/thought”.

By adding an adjective to that noun, as in *rapida mente*, it therefore indicates in a rapid manner. You can see why the adjective has to agree with a **feminine** noun: because *mens* itself was **feminine**.

This is also why you can chain together adverbs in Spanish by using a sequence of **feminine** adjectives saving up the *-mente* adverbial suffix for the last adjective in the series:

> Se lo explicó ***lenta, clara* y *cariñosa*mente**.

That *-mente* suffix on the last term, *cariñosa**-mente***, distributes to both the earlier terms *lenta* and *clara*. But you do not use [suspension hyphens](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/130143/2085) in Spanish for this as one might do in English.

### Body and Mind

This Romance habit of using a version of “mind” to derive adverbs from directly in lieu of using a longer phrase corresponds to the Germanic habit of using a version of “body” to do so.  We no longer think about it, but the English *-ly* suffix comes from a word that meant “body”, [*lich*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lich#English).  This practice also occurs in related languages like Dutch and German.

So where Romance tongues use a “mind” suffix, Germanic ones use a “body” suffix for the same purpose.

---

---

---

<sup>(traducción suelta)</sup>

#### Pregunta original:

> > Para formar adverbios en español, se toma el adjetivo elegido, como por
> > ejemplo *lento*, se pone en forma femenina como *lenta* y entonces se añade el
> > sufijo *‑mente* para llegar al adverbio, *lentamente*.  ¿Por qué usas la forma
> > femenina aquí?
> >
> > En la mayoría de los casos en que no importa el género, se usa la
> > forma masculina en castellano, pero este caso no funciona así: ¿por qué no?

---

## En latín se produjo *mente* en caso ablativo del vocablo *mens, mentis*

Esta práctica comenzó en el latín clásico, pasó al latín vulgar y al
proto-romance y de ahí a todas las lenguas romances occidentales modernas:
el italiano, el castellano, el asturiano, el gallego, el portugués, el
aragonés, el catalán, el occitano, el francés y los otros muchos idiomas
vecinos que pertenecen a ese grupo amplio.

Se deriva *la mente*, ahora un sustantivo femenino en español moderno, del
mismo lejano origen latino como igualmente se deriva el sufijo *‑mente* que
se usa para derivar “adverbios de manera” de adjetivos: *mens, mentis*, un
sustantivo femenino de la tercera declinación latina. Este sustantivo
significa pensamiento o mente, siendo este último el cognato de la
palabra inglesa *mind* a través de un ancestro proto-indoeuropeo común.

En cuanto a su etimología, [dice el diccionario de la Real Academia
Española](https://dle.rae.es/-mente#Owj95I8):

> ### *‑mente*
>
> Del latín *mente*, ablativo de *mens, mentis* ‘inteligencia’, ‘propósito’.
>
> 1. elemento compositivo. Forma adverbios a partir de adjetivos. *Fácilmente, pobremente.*

El Wikcionario español dice lo siguiente en [su entrada para la voz latina
*mens*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mens#Lat%C3%ADn):

> #### Etimología
>
> Del protoitálico **mn̥ti‑*, y este del protoindoeuropeo **mn̥tís*,
> o bien **méntis*. Compárese el sánscrito *मति* (*matí*)
> (“pensamiento”, “mente”), el avéstico *maiti* (“pensamiento”, “idea”),
> el lituano *mintis* (“pensamiento”, “idea”), el eslavo eclesiástico
> antiguo *pamęъ* (“memoria”, “monumento”), el gótico 
> (*anaminds*) (ana‑*minds* “sospecha”) y  (*gaminþi*)
> (ga‑*minþi* “memoria”) y el alemán antiguo *gimunt* (gi‑*munt*
> “memoria”). Además el inglés antiguo *gemynd* (“pensamiento”), a su vez
> origen del inglés *mind* (“mente”).

Y finalmente [se nota en la entrada correspondiente en inglés](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mens#Usage_notes):

> #### Usage notes
>
> In most classical Latin, the ablative singular *mente* was used with a
> feminine adjective to form a phrasal adverb that expressed a person’s state
> of mind, such as *vēlōcī mente* (“quick-mindedly, with a quick mind”):
>
> - 1st century BCE, Catullus, poem 8, line 11:
>   *sed **obstinata mente** perfer, obdura*
>   but with a resolved mind, endure, hold out.
> - 29–19 BCE, Virgil, *Aenid*, book 4, line 105:
>   *sensit enim **simulata mente** locutam*
>   for she realized that (she) had spoken with false purpose.
>
> In Late Latin, this construction began to be extended to other adjectives
> and uses as well, and in Vulgar Latin and the later Romance languages, it
> became a general adverbial suffix.
>
> - 8th century, Reichenau Glosses:
>   *singulariter pro solamente*
>   *singulariter* for/instead of *solamente*

El [caso ablativo tenía varios usos distintos en latín
antiguo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ablative_(Latin)) que ahora solemos
representar con una preposición en lugar de una inflexión nominal del caso,
la que ya no tenemos. Una de estas preposiciones que hoy en día utilizamos
en castellano para traducir el antiguo caso ablativo es ***con***. Por eso
cuando los romanos usaban *mens* en caso ablativo, significaban “**con**
(una / la) mente” o bien “**con** (un / el) pensamiento”.

Cuando usaban un adjetivo con ese sustantivo, como p.ej. *rapida mente*,
por lo tanto esto indicaba “de manera rápida”. Puedes ver por qué el
adjetivo tenía que concordar con un sustantivo femenino: porque *mens* era
palabra femenina en aquel entonces.

Esto también nos da la explicación por la curiosa práctica castellana de
encadenar adverbios usando una secuencia de adjetivos femeninos que guardan
el sufijo *‑mente* adverbial para el último adjetivo de la serie:

> Se lo explicó ***lenta, clara* y *cariñosa*mente**.

Como ves, ese sufijo *‑mente* del último término, *cariñosa**‑mente***,
distribuye a ambos términos anteriores, *lenta* y *clara*. Pero en español
no se usan los así llamados [“guiones de
suspensión”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/130143/2085) como en
inglés.

### Cuerpo y mente

Este hábito romance de usar una versión de *mens, mente* para derivar adverbios
directamente en lugar de usar una frase más larga corresponde al hábito
germánico de usar una versión de su palabra para *cuerpo* para hacer la
mismita cosa. Y aunque nunca piensan en ello, la verdad es que el sufijo inglés *‑ly* viene
de una palabra que de antaño significaba “cuerpo”: [*lich*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lich). También ocurre
esta práctica en otros idiomas germánicos relacionados al inglés como el
holandés y el alemán.

Entonces cuando en las lenguas romances usamos un sufijo derivado de
“mente” para crear adverbios de manera, en las lenguas germánicas
usan un sufijo derivado de “cuerpo” con el mismo propósito.

Comment: Fascinating! Do you know if the body/mind difference is due to a common route in PIE or some such thing?

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey No, I don’t know that at all, and would not venture a guess.

Comment: You didn't mention one major romance language: Romanian

Comment: @curt I did in a deleted comment. They don't use *-mente*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the DRAE [here](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Owj95I8) the suffix *-mente* comes from the Latin mens (which also gives us the Spanish *mente*). Since that is feminine presumably the adjective agreed with it. So you originally said *de lenta mente* or some such. There is also, in the entry for *mente* itself the phrase *de buena mente*

Comment: The link doesn't say anything about femininity. Am I missing something?

Comment: The entry about mente is not linked, but it's in http://dle.rae.es/?id=OwgZLgt