# ¿Llevan tilde los adverbios terminados en -mente?

Tags: acentuación, adverbios

Tengo cierta confusión sobre si deben escribirse con o sin tilde los adverbios terminados en *-mente*: ¿*efectivamente* o *efectívamente*?

Al añadírsele el sufijo *-mente*, todas ellas pasan a ser esdrújulas, por lo que según las reglas de ortografía deberían llevarla.

Además, ¿cómo se pronuncian? ¿*efecTIvaMENte* o *efecTIvamente*?

Comment: Gracias por esta pregunta. De hecho, el otro día me corregiste en un _edit_ "simplemente", que yo tenía con tilde en la "i" y tenía pendiente repasarme las reglas, porque estaba convencido de que era una sobreesdrújula y se tenía que acentuar.

Comment: @Diego me alegro que te haya servido. De hecho fue [esa revisión](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/19400/revisions) la que me hizo dudar a mí, porque pensé: "Si Diego lo escribe así tendrá sus motivos" :) Al ser una regla contraria a la intuición, creí que merecía una pregunta-respuesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Llevan tilde si lo lleva el adjetivo del que derivan.**

---

Tal y como indica la RAE [en Twitter](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/690256387465682944):

> [#RAEconsultas](https://twitter.com/hashtag/RAEconsultas) Los adverbios en «-mente» conservan la tilde del adjetivo base si este la lleva: ágilmente (ágil), cordialmente (cordial).

Si buscamos un poco más, en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas (DPD) encontramos lo siguiente en la entrada de *[acento](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ)*:

> 4. Acentuación de palabras y expresiones compuestas
>
> [**4.2. Adverbios en -mente**](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ#42). Los adverbios terminados en *-mente* se pronuncian, de forma natural y no enfática, con dos sílabas tónicas: la que corresponde al adjetivo del que derivan y la del elemento compositivo *-mente* (*LENtaMENte*). **Estas palabras conservan la tilde, si la había, del adjetivo del que derivan**: *fácilmente* (de *fácil*), *rápidamente* (de *rápido*); pero *cordialmente* (de *cordial*), *bruscamente* (de *brusco*).

En cuanto a la acentuación fonética, el DPD incide en lo descrito más arriba, dando algo más de detalle:

> [**acento**](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=xwnL0rH8RD6olZ8prm). Hay que distinguir entre el acento prosódico, que es el mayor relieve con que se pronuncia una determinada sílaba dentro de una palabra, y el acento gráfico u ortográfico —también llamado tilde—, que es el signo con el cual, en determinados casos, se representa en la escritura el acento prosódico.
>
> 1. Acento prosódico.
> 1.1. Palabras tónicas y átonas.
> a) Palabras tónicas. (...) Los adverbios terminados en -mente son las únicas palabras que se pronuncian, de manera natural y no enfática, con dos sílabas tónicas: la que corresponde al adjetivo del que derivan y la del elemento compositivo -mente, cuya primera sílaba es tónica: HÁbilMENte, aLEgreMENte (sobre la acentuación gráfica de estas palabras, → tilde2, 4.2).

Comment: Esto ocurre porque, a pesar de escribirlos en una palabra, el origen de los adverbios se basa en una locución con el sustantivo *mente* y un adjetivo que concordaba con él (por eso usamos la forma femenina).  Habiendo dos palabras diferentes, había dos acentos y aunque ahora los escribimos en una palabra, todavía no están completa y totalmente fusionadas (¿ves lo que hice? jaja) y las reglas normales no sirven tanto.  Tal vez merecería la pena incluir un poco sobre la etimología para explicarlo

Comment: @guifa el ejemplo está ágil e inteligentemente encontrado jaja. Creo que la interesante pregunta [Etimología y origen de la terminación “-mente”](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19468/1674), junto con [Why are Spanish adverbs formed using the feminine?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18354/1674) son un buen complemento a esta respuesta. Dejo pues la respuesta como está a la espera de ver si la pregunta de Carlos Alejo recibe alguna aportación útil que pueda enlazar desde aquí.