# Profundizando en los adverbios terminados en «-mente»: ¿son inclasificables en cuanto a la posición de su acento prosódico?

Tags: acentuación, adverbios, fonología

Siguiendo el hilo de *[¿Llevan tilde los adverbios terminados en -mente?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19465/12637)*, y aprovechando que la RAE había retuiteado su tuit acerca de si los adverbios en *-mente* llevan o no tilde, se produjo [la siguiente conversación](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/931606514623766528) en dicha red social:

> RAE: Los adverbios en «-mente» conservan la tilde del adjetivo base si este la lleva: ágilmente (ágil), cordialmente (cordial).
>
> YO: Sin embargo, cuando pronuncio "cordialmente", ¿en qué sílaba debo poner el acento?
>
> [LETRA Ñ](https://twitter.com/letraeneoficial): «Cordial» es una palabra aguda y, por ende, lleva acento prosódico, mas no tilde diacrítica. De allí que el adverbio «cordialmente» no lleve tilde diacrítica.
>
> YO: Esto no responde a mi pregunta. Hablo de pronunciar. ¿En qué sílaba se pone el acento en "cordialmente"? ¿Es llana o esdrújula? ¿O ambas?

Nótese que esta pregunta la hice con un poquito de mala idea.

> LETRA Ñ: En tal caso, el acento prosódico irá en la sílaba «al» [cordiálmente]. De modo que el adverbio será una esdrújula.
>
> YO: Y si es una esdrújula, ¿por qué no lleva tilde? ¿Qué diferencia a "cordialmente" de "pásamelo"? A fin de cuentas, "pasa" no lleva tilde. ¿Por qué añadir "me" y "lo" hace que la palabra pase a tener tilde y añadir "mente" no?

A partir de aquí la cuenta "Letra Ñ" queda fuera de juego, y entra la RAE a sustituir:

> RAE: «Cordialmente» no es palabra esdrújula porque se pronuncia con dos acentos: [kordiálménte]. El elemento «-mente» es tónico. «Pásamelo» se pronuncia con un solo acento en el verbo, [pásamelo], por eso es sobresdrújula. «Me» y «lo» son prons. átonos.
>
> YO: Si los adverbios acabados en "mente" son las únicas palabras que se pronuncian con dos acentos, ¿no sería más fiel a la pronunciación escribir "cordial mente" (separado) como se hacía allá por el siglo XIV?
>
> RAE: Aunque originalmente fuese un sustantivo, el elemento «-mente» hoy no lo es. Los adverbios en «-mente» constituyen unidades léxicas para las que la grafía más adecuada es la de una sola palabra.

Y recuperando mi anterior pregunta, añade:

> RAE: «Cordialmente» [kordiálménte] tiene dos sílabas tónicas, «dial» y «men»; no es ni llana ni esdrújula. Los adverbios en «-mente» tienen dos acentos. Para percibirlos, compare la pron. de «médicamente» [médikaménte] con la de «medicamento» [medikaménto].
>
> YO: Pensaba que todas las palabras del español se podían clasificar según la posición de su acento prosódico. Si "cordialmente" no es ni llana ni esdrújula, ¿qué es? ¿Podría decirse más bien que es llana y esdrújula al mismo tiempo?
>
> RAE: Como ya le hemos dicho, los adverbios en «-mente» son palabras con dos acentos. La clasificación de palabras agudas, llanas, esdrújulas y sobresdrújulas no afecta solo a las palabras de más de una sílaba con un acento prosódico.

Entiendo que este último tuit quería decir que "la clasificación de palabras en agudas, llanas... sólo afecta a las palabras con un único acento prosódico".

El caso es que [no sería la primera vez que la cuenta de Twitter de la RAE se columpia a la hora de dar opiniones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17172/12637). Así que me gustaría que me ayudarais a buscar en la Ortografía o la Gramática (o donde sea) la siguiente información:

**¿Es cierto que los adverbios acabados en «-mente» son inclasificables en cuanto a la posición de su acento por tener dos? ¿Realmente dicha clasificación solo afecta a las palabras con un único acento prosódico? ¿Dónde viene eso recogido? ¿Existe alguna clasificación para las palabras con más de un acento prosódico, o eso es terreno desconocido?**

Comment: Creo que le estás dando vueltas de más. Los adverbios en «-mente» no son clasificables en una clasificación que solo considera UN acento, ya que tienen DOS acentos. Simplemente.

Etimológica y fonológicamente los adverbios en «-mente» son dos palabras (https://blog.lengua-e.com/2007/origen-de-los-adverbios-terminados-en-mente/), aunque se escriben en una sola. Se ve la "autonomía" en que decimos cosas como «rápida y fácilmente» mejor que «rápidamente y fácilmente».

Comment: @Paco lo que me lleva a la siguiente pregunta que me hacía: si etimológica y fonológicamente son dos palabras, ¿por qué no las escribimos como dos palabras? Y si las unimos en una palabra que además no es clasificable según la posición de su acento, ¿por qué mantener la tilde en unos sí y otros no en vez de eliminar la tilde en todas ellas?

Comment: ¡Me explotó la mente con eso de que hay palabras con dos acentos!

Comment: @walen de hecho yo me conozco ese chiste como "la única capital de provincia que se acentúa en todas las vocales": "Zárágózá".

Answer (score 1):

La clasificación de palabras en *llana, grave, esdrújula,* y *sobreesdrújula* sólo es útil hasta cierto punto.  Tomemos *vigesimocuarto* como ejemplo.  No encuentro esta palabra en ningún diccionario.  Nos toca hacer la descomposición en sus elementos, "vigésimo" y "cuarto", que sí se encuentran en los diccionarios.

Quizás te sentirías mejor si te pusieras a pensar en las palabras compuestas de inglés y alemán.  Los elementos se juntan con una especie de cinta durex, y te das cuenta cómo pronunciarlas por tomar en cuenta la pronunciación original de las partes componentes.  Así podrás quedar más tolerante de la aparente contradicción que expusiste en tu pregunta.  Ejemplos del inglés y alemán: *lighthouse*, *Weichei*.  Si no entendiera uno las partes componentes, se podrían tomar como *ligh-thouse* y *Wei-chei*.  Pero se deben tomar como *light-house* y *Weich-ei* (weich = blando, Ei = huevo, por lo tanto, huevo pasado por agua).

Mirando un ejemplo de una palabra compuesta en español: *cantamañanas*.  Me imagino que se pronuncia así: *cántamañánas*.  Se puede clasificar como *llana, grave, esdrújula,* o *sobreesdrújula*?  Creo que no.  Creo que el diccionario no nos indica el acento secundario (*can*), porque se supone que el lector va a tomar en cuenta la pronunciación de cada elemento.  A fin de cuentas, no se indican los acentos secundarios en los diccionarios porque no es la costumbre en español.

Vigesimocuarto no se pronuncia vígesímocuárto, sino vigésimocuárto.

Comment: @walen - ¿Es cantámañánas o cántamañánas?  Es decir, ¿cúantas sílabas tiene cada grupo de mis ejemplos?  Creo yo que hay tres sílabas en el grupo *cantama*, pero no tengo certeza en esto.