# Are there any Spanish words with multiple accents?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, diacríticos

I recently saw the word [*súbitáneamente*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=s%C3%BAbit%C3%A1neamente), with two accent marks.

Now, this is clearly an error, which appears to originate from an OCR transcription of [this dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=G7sNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1261&lpg=PA1261&dq=s%C3%BAbit%C3%A1neamente), mistaking a comma on the line above for an accent.

Nonetheless, do there exist any words in Spanish with more than one diacritic?

Comment: Your question says "diacritic" but your title says "accent".

Comment: @chrylis in the context of 'marks on letters' they're [synonyms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/accent), no? I mean, I imagine there are some contexts where people might want to use the two contrastively, maybe limiting *accents* to marks on vowels, using *diacritics* as marks on **any** letter etc, but as is I don't see an issue with using both words in the question (especially given that Spanish doesn't use cedillas etc, only marking vowels).

Comment: In Spanish, an "accent" is a specific mark, and the answers explain the relevance of the distinction.

Comment: @chrylis that's not really true, *accent* not being a Spanish word. I think you're identifying *accent* with *tilde/acento gráfico* when the word is not necessarily that narrow in scope. My question was purposefully broad to include the dieresis as well as acute accent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Asides from words with a *ü* and an accented stress:

> - agüío, aragüirá, changüí, chigüí, chigüín, fragüín, güeldrés, güillín, güirís, güisquería, güérmeces, lengüetería, paragüería, pirgüín, sinvergüencería, yangüés, yegüería, yegüerío, zagüía, 
>     lingüístico, etnolingüística, metalingüístico, metalingüísticamente, psicolingüística, sociolingüístico
> - pedigüeñería

and words with multiple *ü*:

> - güegüecho, güegüenche, güergüero

There are none.

Even loanwords with multiple accents have this reduced to [n]one once they are nativised:

> - [demodé](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C9ehPZB) < démodé `(French)`

---

There are some language groups with hyphenated names where each component of the word has an accent, e.g. [*Paraná-Mamoré*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_arawak_Paran%C3%A1-Mamor%C3%A9), [*motilón-barí*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_bar%C3%AD), [*tupí-guaraní*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguas_tup%C3%AD-guaran%C3%AD), [*fulniô-yatê*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_fulni%C3%B4-yat%C3%AA) etc. But there are no such words that the RAE recognises, all similar examples only come from components with at most one accent in total e.g. *gallego-portugués*, *camito-semítico* etc.

Comment: Good one! I got more or less the same results using this [List with around 80K Spanish words](https://github.com/javierarce/palabras/blob/master/listado-general.txt) and doing some Grepping (`awk -F'[áéíóúü]' 'NF>3' file` and so on).

Answer (score 6):

If you consider the dieresis a diacritic then yes: **lingüística**.

Otherwise, because the **´** marks the stressed syllable and no words (except for adverbs ending in *-mente*) have two stressed syllables, it's not possible to have two written **´** marks, unless the word is directly imported and then should be written in italics.

Comment: Well, in Spain we have `Zárágózá` (_la única palabra del mundo que tiene cuatro acentos para los maños_).

Answer (score 2):

**In case you just mean: " ´ " (not "ñ"!!)**

No, there is NOT a Spanish word with more than one accent. The maximum is one accent.

That is because the accent marks the emphasis of a word - in Spanish you ALWAYS just emphasize one syllable per word - so:

- maximum ONE emphasis per word = maximum one accent per word.

Comment: The original question shows "súbitamente".  But when that word is pronounced the stress falls on the penultimate syllable (not the first).  So either the original dictionary is wrong and "subitamente" doesn't have an accent when written, or else the written accent is not always the emphasized syllable.

Comment: @EdAvis - Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19465/9385

Comment: @EdAvis in *súbitamente* the stress falls on *both* the first and next-to-last syllable (and are equally stressed).  I explain it a bit in a comment I made in the post aparente001 linked to.

Comment: yes.... and no.... words will have only one explicit accent, but there are words with more than one tonic syllable, specially compounded words, as they will normally keep the emphasis of both worlds. specially words ending with mente

Comment: Thanks for link.  I guess I was particularly questioning Nico's assertion that "maximum ONE emphasis per word".  In súbitamente there are two emphasized syllables.  So I think the answer needs tweaking a bit.

Comment: No pienso en mi vida haber pronunciado *súbitamente* de ninguna otra forma aparte de la que es marcada como tal. Es decir, creo erroneas las pronunciaciones que suenan como *subitámente*, *súbitámente*, *subítamente* o *súbitaménte*. Se siente el estrés solamente en la sílaba **sú**. Es importante recordar que en cuestiones de palabras que terminan en *mente*, se determina dónde se coloca el acento basado en la palabra base, es decir, en este caso es la palabra *súbito/a*

Comment: @psosuna I’m fairly sure that’s not correct. Based on everything I’ve learned and have been able to find, one of the last three syllables in any accented Spanish word (not counting unstressed clitics, which do not influence stress assignment) **must** always be stressed, no matter what. [This article](https://hispadoc.es/descarga/articulo/4243729.pdf) (p. 3, with further references) by Mark Gibson of the University of Navarra says that, “this seems to be one of few steadfast rules which is never violated by Spanish stress application”.

Comment: @psosuna Similarly, [this article](https://www.academia.edu/3981703/On_the_Morphological_Nature_of_Spanish_Adverbs_Ending_in_-mente) (p. 119) by Sergi Torner states that, “the _-mente_ adverbs in Spanish have a double accentuation, … **despite the fact that _-mente_ is tonic**” (my emphasis). These two taken together is enough to convince me that words like _súbitamente_ are indeed generally pronounced [ˈsuβitaˈmente] or [ˌsuβitaˈmente] (i.e., _súbitaménte_), and not [*ˈsuβitamente]. If that is how you’ve been pronouncing it your whole life, I would venture that you are more or less alone.