# Etimología y origen de la terminación "-mente"

Tags: etimología, historia, adverbios, sufijos

Según la RAE, el elemento compositivo *-mente* tiene [la siguiente etimología](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Owj95I8):

> Del lat. *mente*, abl. de *mens, mentis* 'inteligencia', 'propósito'.

Etimología que comparte con el sustantivo *mente*, que en 1734 significaba:

> Lo mismo que entendimiento.
>
> ---
>
> Se toma también por sentido, inteligencia ù objeto de alguna cosa.

De hecho, en textos de los siglos XIII al XVI se puede encontrar este sufijo escrito como palabra independiente:

> *Resçebir muy **honrrada mente** con grand proçesion [...].* (1293)
>
> ---
>
> *[...] e juro e prometo a buena fed sin mal a Dios e a Santo Toribio e sobre los Santos Abangelios tomandolos **corporal mente** con mis manos de nunca demandar otra presentasion a vos [...].* (1352)
>
> ---
>
> *[...] e por ende enesto sienpre nos trabajamos de fazer leyes e ordenamientos quantos **buena mente** pudiesemos, con acuerdo de aquellos que nos ouieren de consejar, [...].* (1390)
>
> ---
>
> *Por que vos mando a todos e acada vno de vos que guardedes e conplades e fagades guardar e conplir desde agora en adelante **rreal mente** e con efecto estas mis leyes e hordenanças de suso [...].* (1471)
>
> ---
>
> *E avn tanto estrañaron esta pelea que mandaron que los que andan **cotidiana mente** con el rey por la conpaña que han deso vno por la hermandat [...].* (1491)
>
> ---
>
> *[...] sea obligado a les tener hecha una casa para yglesia, **junta mente** con la dicha hazienda, que se les señalare en la parte que a vos [...].* (1513)

¿Era esta la forma usual de escribir los adverbios en aquella época? También los he encontrado escritos en su forma actual ("publicamente" en un texto de 1208). Igual puede pasar que los textos en los que se escribió separado formaran parte de algún dialecto diferente del que derivó en el castellano, como ya ha pasado en otras preguntas.

En todo caso, ¿por qué se usó la palabra "mente" como creador de adverbios? Cuando la veo en textos escrita de forma separada, como en los ejemplos anteriores, me da la sensación de que en su origen vendría a significar algo así:

- Lentamente: con la mente puesta en hacerlo lento (con lenta mente). O también: con el propósito de hacerlo lento, si atendemos al significado que la RAE da del latín *mens, mentis*.
- Públicamente: con la mente puesta (o el propósito puesto) en hacerlo público.

¿Sería esta una explicación sobre el posible origen del sufijo? ¿O atiende a alguna otra etimología más antigua?

Comment: Hay un paper interesantísimo al respecto: [_Condicionamientos textuales en la evolución
de los adverbios en -mente*_](http://xn--revistadefilologiaespaola-uoc.revistas.csic.es/index.php/rfe/article/viewFile/235/237), así como webs con miga: [Origen de los adverbios terminados en -mente](http://blog.lengua-e.com/2007/origen-de-los-adverbios-terminados-en-mente/) y [De mente eficiente a eficientemente](http://udep.edu.pe/castellanoactual/de-mente-eficiente-a-eficientemente/). Observo cierto discrepancia sobre si viene o no del latín, pero de momento no tengo tiempo para mirar en detalle.

Comment: Sí, era normal escribirlos así.  De hecho, si los encuentras en una, averigua el manuscrito para verificar que no había un proceso de modernización (aunque ojo: tampoco es fácil, a veces, determinar lo que es y no es un espacio.  No es infrecuente ver algo es critoan sí ques di fícil de terminar con toda seguridad :-) )

Comment: Aquí en SE, la respuesta a [Why are Spanish adverbs formed using the feminine?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18354/why-are-spanish-adverbs-formed-using-the-feminine/18357#18357) puede echar algo de luz al respecto. Me resulta fascinante lo de la diferenciación mente/cuerpo entre las lenguas romances y las germánicas.

Comment: I didn't read the answers in detail, but "Why are Spanish adverbs formed using the feminine? " and "Why they use "mente" is definitely not the same thing. "mente" is not a feminine. It seems to imply that!!