# Why do (a lot of) adverbs in Spanish end in -mente?

Tags: gramática, etimología, ortografía, adverbios

¿Por qué muchos adverbios en español terminan con *-mente*? *Fuertemente, lentamente, rápidamente, suavemente, ferozmente, usualmente, cálidamente, fríamente, inteligentemente, silenciosamente*... etc.

Comment: Hello, Sue! Please, could you check the accepted answer to [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18354/12637) and see if it answers yours? If it doesn't, please add more information explaining why so we can solve your specific doubt.

Comment: One might ask: Why do English adverbs end in LY?

Answer (score 3):

Existen tantos adverbios acabados en *-mente* sencillamente porque fue la opción que triunfó entre las muchas posibles que tenía el latín de crear adverbios. Lo explica la *Nueva Gramática* de la RAE en su [párrafo 7.14a](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=hGWoovHsJXXZHfIT) (negritas mías):

> El latín formó numerosos adverbios a partir de adjetivos con los sufijos *-ter* (*brevĭter, dulcĭter, prudenter*), *-ē* (*amīce, alte, longe*), *-im* (*certatim, cursim, privātim*) y algunos otros. Ninguno de ellos pasó a las lenguas romances, con la posible excepción de *inclusīve* y *exclusīve*. Creó, además, adverbios mediante la recategorización de adjetivos de género neutro en acusativo (*multum* 'mucho' o facĭle 'fácilmente') o ablativo (*merĭto 'con razón', 'merecidamente'; *raro* 'raramente'). También originó expresiones adverbiales perifrásticas a partir del ablativo de los sustantivos *opus, -ěris* (*magnopěre* 'en gran medida'; *quantopěre* 'en qué medida'); *vĭa* (*qua vĭa* 'cómo, en qué forma'), aún presente en la etimología del adverbio español *todavía*; *modus* (*onmimŏdo* 'de todas las maneras'; *quamŏdo* 'cómo', *solummŏdo* 'solo, únicamente'); *ratio* (*ea ratiōne* 'por este motivo') y otros sustantivos. **Sobresale entre todos ellos *mente*, ablativo de *mens, mentis*, que no significaba solo 'mente, pensamiento', sino también 'ánimo, intención'. Esta última opción triunfó sobre las demás formas analíticas en el latín tardío y se extendió como sufijo adverbial característico a las lenguas romances.**

De aquí se extrae que ya durante el latín tardío se produjo una simplificación de todas las mencionadas maneras de formar adverbios del latín clásico (aplicando al lenguaje el [principio KISS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS)), por lo que en los primeros compases de lo que hoy consideramos el idioma español ya era la única forma productiva de crear adverbios a partir de adjetivos. De ahí que abunden.

Answer (score 2):

Como dice el Diccionario de la Lengua (negrita mía), el sufijo [**-mente**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Owj95I8)

> Del lat. *mente*, abl. de *mens, mentis* 'inteligencia<sup>1</sup>', 'propósito'.
>   1. elem. compos. **Forma adverbios a partir de adjetivos.** *Fácilmente, pobremente.*

es decir, es un mecanismo para formar adverbios a partir de adjetivos. Y como hay muchos adjetivos, se pueden formar muchos adverbios. Por eso hay tantos.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about it. In English you use -ly

fuertemente -> strongly

rápidamente -> rapidly

suavemente  -> softly

ferozmente  -> fiercely

usualmente  -> usually

cálidamente -> warmly?,

fríamente   -> coldly,

inteligentemente -> inteligently,

silenciosamente -> silently